# Illegal Invocation - FormData - Not understanding why it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get a file from an input file with this method.
I know there is already several topic about this, but i tried everything i could to make it work.

Here's the Form:

```
<form id="sendPDF" method="POST" name="sendPDF" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="attachPDFFile" name="attachPDFFile">
    <input type="hidden" name="idEntite">
    <input type="hidden" name="typeEntite">
    <input type="hidden" id="typeScanPDF" name="typeScan" value="">
</form>
```

And the JQuery code:

```
$("#attachPDFFile").on("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0], 
        data = new FormData();

    data.append('attachPDF', file.name);

    $.ajax({
        url:        siteUrl + "/action/actionCommon/attachPDF",
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'JSON',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: ...
    });
});
```

This returns me an Illegal Invocation...

Could you help me with that ? It's blowing my mind...

Comment: Have a look here : https://www.sanwebe.com/2016/07/ajax-form-submit-examples-using-jquery

Comment: Thx you for your fast answer ^^ I'll check it out

Comment: Do you think that my problem may come from my call ? I use the onChange listener and he uses onSubmit.

Comment: Maybe is success? success: function(result){
        $("#somediv").html(result);
    } . And try to remove dataType

Comment: Hmmm try this : `.on('input',function()` not `.on("change", function()`

Comment: For the success i have : function(data){ console.log(data) }. It doesn't work... I even tried the onSubmit method but still doesn't work :/

Comment: what about .on('input',function()......... ???

Comment: Didn't work too :/